# Mock RestTemplate getForObject

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, resttemplate

I am having difficulties in Mocking RestTemplate.getForObject method. Method definition is

```
public <T> T getForObject(String url, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables) throws RestClientException
```

I am using this method in my service class as following.

```
    User user = restTemplate.getForObject("https://api.github.com/users/{username}", 
                User.class, username);
```

Service method gets "username" as input which I pass to getForObject method.

In my Test method I have Mock Rest Template.

```
doAnswer(new Answer<User>() {
            @Override
            public User answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
                User user = new User();
                user.setLogin("ghtvnath");
                user.setName("Tharindu Vishwanath");
                return user;
            }
        }).when(restTemplate).getForObject(anyString(),
                eq(User.class), anyString());
```

But for some reason this mock doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MockRestServiceServer` instead of mocking the RestTemplate interface.

```
private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    mockServer = createServer(restTemplate);
}


@Test
public void testSomething(){
        mockServer.expect(anything()).andRespond(withSuccess("{\login\":\"ghtvnath\""}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));


}
```